# intl-tel-input - guardar prefijo en base de datos

Tags: php, jquery, formularios

Estoy usando [este](https://www.twilio.com/blog/como-crear-entradas-internacionales-de-numeros-de-telefono-en-html-y-javascript) pluggin para guardar el celular de los usuarios a través de un formulario. Sin embargo, en base de datos solo se almacena el valor que se registra en el campo 'Phone' (sólo el número sin prefijo).

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de extraer el prefijo seleccionado y almacenarlo en la base de datos ya sea en un campo aparte o en el mismo campo con el número de celular:

En resumen, este código es el que está plasmado en mi formulario:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intl-tel-input@17.0.3/build/css/intlTelInput.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intl-tel-input@17.0.3/build/js/intlTelInput.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input id="phone" type="tel" name="phone" />
    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Verify" />
</form>

<script>
    var input = document.querySelector("#phone");
    var iti = window.intlTelInput(input, {
        separateDialCode:true,
        utilsScript: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intl-tel-input@17.0.3/build/js/utils.js",
    });

    // store the instance variable so we can access it in the console e.g. window.iti.getNumber()
    window.iti = iti; 

const phoneNumber = phoneInput.getNumber();
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Agradezco su ayuda,

La función que hace aparecer la lista de prefijos es:

```
 var iti = window.intlTelInput(input, {
        separateDialCode:true,
        utilsScript: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intl-tel-input@17.0.3/build/js/utils.js",
    });
```

Y el valor que guarda el valor del préfijo + el número es:

```
getNumber()
```

Quisiera extraer ese getNumer() y almacenarlo en un campo tipo texto del formulario. (cabe aclarar que el formulario está contruido en php)

Comment: Hola. ¿Dónde exactamente está ese dato que dices querer guardar? ¿Con qué código estás intentando guardarlo? ¿Cuál es el problema o error? Pulsa en [edit] para completar tu pregunta.

Comment: ¿Pero, qué devuelve `getNumber()` actualmente?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que tú estás llamando a `getNumber()` sobre un objeto `phoneInput` que no existe, pues tú llamase al objeto: **`iti`**.

Luego, si te interesa el código del país, examinando el objeto, podrás ver que se encuentra dentro de una propiedad llamada `activeItem` que tiene a su vez [un `dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) con dos propiedades: `dialCode` (que es el valor que te interesa) y `country-code` que es el código del país.

Este es un ejemplo, de lo obtenido haciendo un  `console.log(iti);`: `

```
"activeItem": 
  <li class="iti__country iti__preferred iti__active"   
      tabindex="-1" id="iti-0__item-us-preferred"
      role="option" 
      data-dial-code="1" 
      data-country-code="us" aria-selected="true">
      ...
```

Sabiendo eso, puedes obtener el código del país por separado accediendo al dataset que se encuentra en `activeItem` y obteniendo la propiedad `dial-code` del mismo.

Por ejemplo:

```js
var input = document.querySelector("#phone");
var iti = window.intlTelInput(input, {
  separateDialCode: true,
  utilsScript: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intl-tel-input@17.0.3/build/js/utils.js",
});

// store the instance variable so we can access it in the console e.g. window.iti.getNumber()
window.iti = iti;

document.getElementById("btnSubmit").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const phoneNumber = iti.getNumber();
  console.log(phoneNumber);
  const activeItem = iti.activeItem.dataset;
  console.log(activeItem.dialCode);

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intl-tel-input@17.0.3/build/css/intlTelInput.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intl-tel-input@17.0.3/build/js/intlTelInput.js"></script>


<form>
  <input id="phone" type="tel" name="phone" />
  <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" class="btn" value="Verify" />
</form>
```

Si tú quieres pasar esos datos al servidor, puedes ponerlos en un elemento del formulario, o crear un objeto y pasarlos al servidor vía Ajax.

Por ejemplo:

```js
var input = document.querySelector("#phone");
var ibxCode = document.querySelector("#ibxCode");

var iti = window.intlTelInput(input, {
  separateDialCode: true,
  utilsScript: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intl-tel-input@17.0.3/build/js/utils.js",
});

window.iti = iti;

document.getElementById("btnSubmit").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const phoneNumber = iti.getNumber();
  const activeItem = iti.activeItem.dataset;
  ibxCode.value = activeItem.dialCode;

  /*
    Si es para mandarlo por Ajax o Fetch
    construyes un objeto como este
    y lo mandas. Y en el servidor los recuperas
    usando las claves de la izquierda:
    ibxCode y phone
  */
  var mData = {
    ibxCode: activeItem.dialCode,
    phone: input.value
  };
  console.log(mData);


  console.log(phoneNumber);
  console.log(activeItem.dialCode);

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intl-tel-input@17.0.3/build/css/intlTelInput.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intl-tel-input@17.0.3/build/js/intlTelInput.js"></script>


<form>
  <input id="phone" type="tel" name="phone" />
  <input id="ibxCode" type="number" name="ibxCode" placeholder="Código de País" readOnly disabled/>

  <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" class="btn" value="Verify" />
</form>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, súper claro

Comment: @DayanaPGaleano revisa la respuesta editada, he explicado cómo poner el código en un elemento de formulario (por si usas el mismo formulario para enviar los datos al servidor) y también explico cómo crear un objeto (en el caso de que uses Ajax o Fetch para pasar los datos al servidor). Puedes usar una u otra forma, según el caso. Es mucho mejor usar Ajax o Fetch, pero ese es otro asunto.